# Is there a way to match when the cell has several values

Tags: excel, vba

I am reading the data from one column F2:F11 of an excel worksheet that has this data

```
|SAT|
|SAT|
|SAT|
|SAT|
|M, T, TH, SAT|
|SUN, W|
|SUN, W, F|
|SAT|
|T, F, SUN|
|W|
```

I'm using this vba code to get the matches to Saturday (SAT)

```
Sub Test()

Dim WaterDays As Range
Set myWKS = Worksheets("Water")
Set WaterDays = myWKS.Range("F2:F11")

For Each y In WaterDays
   vParts = Split(y, ",")
   For Each dy In vParts
      If StrComp(dy, "SAT") = 0 Then
        Debug.Print ("Yes")
      End If
   Next dy
 Next y
End Sub
```

When I do this it will give me 5 matches (Yes), when there are actually 6 SATs in the column.  What am I doing wrong here?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: How about `If dy Like "*SAT*" Then`  ? .. Or without vParts and dy `If y Like "*SAT*" Then`  ?

Comment: Change 'If StrComp(dy, "SAT") = 0 Then' to 'If Instr(dy,"SAT")>0 then'

Comment: Thanks..Inst works for SAT but if you do this for a Tuesday (T) will match with Sat, Th, and T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a non-breaking space in |M, T, TH, SAT| before SAT.

This is fixed in the following code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

Debug.Print "--- check for SAT"
checkForWeekday "SAT"

Debug.Print "--- check for TU"
checkForWeekday "TU"
End Sub


Public Sub checkForWeekday(strDay As String)

Dim WaterDays As Range
Set myWKS = Worksheets("Water")
Set WaterDays = myWKS.Range("F2:F11")


Dim arrValues As Variant
arrValues = WaterDays.Value2

Dim i As Long, values As String

For i = 1 To UBound(arrValues, 1)
    values = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(arrValues(i, 1)) 'clean other non-printable signs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.clean
    values = Replace(values, Chr(160), " ") 'non-breaking space
    
    values = "|" & Replace(values, ", ", "|") & "|"   'add comma at the beginning and the end to have clear separators
    If InStr(values, "|" & strDay & "|") Then    'then you can check for |*|
        Debug.Print values, "yes"
    Else
        Debug.Print values, "no"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Ike...I just ran and got 'no' for everything.  Must say, it seems like this should work.

Comment: Does the values-part in the debug-window look correct?

Comment: This is what I get
https://pasteboard.co/zGVWer2ihJp8.png

Comment: There is no T like in your sample set from the question. And I misunderstood the |-sign - I thought it is part of the cell content. But it looks like if not. I adjust the code

Comment: I updated the code ... please try again

Comment: Here is the result...https://pasteboard.co/gWwTmRXc1Qoq.png
Yes, there is no | between the cells...that was forced by not letting me put in a pic to show the table - I had to use code for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237487/discussion-between-ike-and-allen).

Answer (score 2):

When you split string `M, T, TH, SAT` by comma you get space in resulting strings, so use `TRIM` function:

```
...StrComp(Trim(dy), "SAT")...
```

**Edit**

You have non breaking spaces in some strings so you need combine `Trim` and `Substitute`:

```
Sub Test()

Dim WaterDays As Range, cel As Range
Set myWKS = Worksheets("Water")
Set WaterDays = myWKS.Range("F2:F11")

For Each y In WaterDays
   vParts = Split(y, ",")
   For Each dy In vParts
      tdy = Application.Substitute(Trim(dy), Chr(160), "")
      If StrComp(tdy, "SAT") = 0 Then
        Debug.Print ("Yes")
      End If
   Next dy
 Next y
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks...just tried that...still get 5 matches instead of 6

Comment: @Allen In some strings you have non breaking space so ```Trim``` not working always. See edit.

Comment: Thanks..well, that still gives me 5 yeses.  is the problem that Trim is leaving a white space due to a line break or something like that?

Comment: @Allen Yes, it might be problem. Trim removes just leading and trailing spaces. If there are other chars before or after it leaves space intact.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
If InStr(1, dy, "SAT", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
```

instead of

```
If StrComp(dy, "SAT") = 0 Then
```

You don't even have to split the cell content and just run that check on its value

```
            For Each y In WaterDays
            
                If InStr(1, y.Value2, "SAT", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    Debug.Print "Yes"
                End If
                        
            Next
```

Finally, should you be interested in counting the "SAT"s only , than you don't need any loop at all

```
        Set WaterDays = myWKS.Range("F2:F11")

            Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.CountIf(WaterDays, "*SAT*")
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there was a non-breaking space, but to handle this I needed to substitute Chr(240) and not Chr(160).